# Adding an item to the Google Drive UI

Tags: google-drive-api

I need to add a new item to the left sidebar on Google Drive (under 'Starred', 'Trash', 'Recent', etc.).

Is it possible?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not with any api. Your only option is to write a browser extension.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try creating a Greasemonkey/Tampermonkey script

Comment: Well, it would be a browser extension after all ;-)

Comment: Yes, but not exactly a proper extension. Though depending on your needs, it may be enough

Answer (score 0):

Writing a browser extension did the trick.

Thank you.